# Oracle Db Sorting Issue for Turkish Text

Tags: spring, oracle, sorting, spring-data-jpa

We're developing project with Spring Boot (JPA-Spring-Data) and Oracle Db. When trying to sort column which includes text, oracle gives me wrong sorting for Turkish Chars. Liquibase is our db migration tool.

This is a script for creation of table's column;

```
<column name="CONTENT" type="VARCHAR2(255 char)">
 <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

Entitys property;

```
@Column(name = "CONTENT", nullable = false)
private String content;
```

[image: Column]

When trying to order by Content; The result looks like below

[image]

But for example; İngilizceeee row would be after 'I' letter. There is an issue for Turkish text.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses binary sort by default. This works by sorting the numerical value behind the character encoding. This works well for the English alphabet because the ASCII and EBCDIC standards define the letters A to Z in ascending numeric value.
Try using 'Linquistic Sort'. See here -

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch4.htm

Example -

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY NLSSORT(name, 'NLS_SORT=german');
```

Comment: I have just edited my question, I use JPA. Solution would be implement with jpa or properity config not in the database sql query

Comment: Does setting it at session level work for you? Like this - 'Alter session set nls_sort=GERMAN'

Comment: Do I have to set nls_sort in Db layer ? Is there any chance to do it in Jpa or java or application properties etc.

Comment: You should be able to set it in your java application. When a new connection is created, set it on the connection by executing 'Alter session' statement. You can probably hook into some callback from your connection pool implementation. So, whenever a new connection is added to the pool, your callback will get invoked where you can run your 'alter session' statement.